# Problem peers in a cluster [SOLVED]

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, peers

I have a cluster with 2 nodes and I would like to create a testnet by connecting them with geth.

I am using the following command:

```
Node1:
geth --datadir node1 --port 30302 --rpc --rpcport 3003 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.2 --ipcpath node1/geth.ipc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 15 --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsport 3002 --wsorigins "*"

Node2:
geth --datadir node2 --port 30304 --rpc --rpcport 3005 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.2 --ipcpath node2/geth.ipc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 15 --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsport 3004 --wsorigins "*"
```

and both work individually. When I try to add them as peer, if does not work

```
admin.addPeer("....@127.0.0.1:30304")
```

Although the exit of this command is true, the peer is not added. Any idea?

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, so it can help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: It is necessary to check the ip address of each node and write it to --rcpaddr yourip. Then: admin.addPeer("....@yourip:yourport")